# nginx as proxy to squid forward proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, squid

what I'm trying to understand the feasibility is to create a completely transparent system for any client's browser that allows me to visit any destination url using a syntax like:

what I am trying to do is perfectly reported, but no solution provieded here http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2008-December/008987.html

https://example.com/<uri_to_visit>.

the system has to work as if browser is confgured to use a proxy but I don't want to force users to configure proxy parameter.

I thought to use nginx to proxy the uri requests and then squid to process the request. nginx and squid are on the same server but may also be on different servers.
I'm trying  to  access to any website ( for example  ) google.com
from any browser using

```
"https://example.com/service/google.com"
```

example.com is  managed by one of my nginx web server

Following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331813/reverse-proxy-from-nginx-to-squid

nginx config section has been set as follows:

```
location ~* ^/service/(.*) {  
                                                                                                     
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3128/$1$is_args$args;                                                                                                                                                                
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                                                                       
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                   
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                                                                                    
    proxy_set_header Request-URI $request_uri;     
    proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                                
                                                                                                                                   
    proxy_redirect off;                                                                                                            
}
```

and squid.conf

```
http_port 3128 vhost allow-direct
```

now, when I try to access to https://example.com/service/google.com
squid logs report.

I suppose is question regarding proxy_pass but  I have made many attempts and
have not been able to fix it correctly.

squid.log

```
TCP_MISS/403 4495 GET http://example.com/google.com - HIER_NONE/- text/html
TCP_MISS/403 4589 GET http://example.com/google.com - ORIGINAL_DST/127.0.0.1 text/html
```

Comment: This approach won't take you far. All URLs returned in the HTML from the origin server refer to original URLs, so once user clicks on a URL, he will bypass the proxy.

Comment: There is already proxy software that does this correctly, including rewriting links in documents. Why don't you just use something existing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok plese give me some reference to the software as you say  already do this kind of job

Comment: @MichaelHampton you let this question just starve, i join the question to let us know how ;)